# IndexOutOfBoundsException when I try to create a JTable model

Tags: java

When I try to add my `JTable` to my frame I recieve this error: 
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class tablaFormato extends AbstractTableModel {

List<String[]> topFives = new ArrayList <String[]>();

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 5;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 5;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

    Object resultado = topFives.get(rowIndex) [columnIndex];

    return resultado;
}

}
```

The problem is in `resultado` but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: How do you use `getValueAt`?

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: Can you show which items are stored in topFives

Comment: `I'm a n00b with Java and i cant resolve this issue with mi JTable model.` - then use the DefaultTableModel so you don't have to reinvent the wheel until you understand better how a JTable and TableModel work.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getRowCount()` should return the size of the list else you're telling the JTable, "hey, I've got 5 rows", when in reality you've initially got zip, zero, zilch.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, you're trying to get an element from an empty list.
You need to put something in the list before you can get it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is surely pointing to the line (see the line number in your exception)

Object resultado = topFives.get(rowIndex) [columnIndex];

The getRowCount() method tells the table how many rows are to display
The getColumnCount() method says how many columns are to display in each row

Now the table has enough info to get the data one by one. It starts at row 0, column 0, then row 0 column 1, etc until it reaches what you answered in getColumnCount(). then it goes to row 1 and does the same.

In your case, as soon as it askes for the object in row 0 column 0, an exception is thrown because you're trying to get from topFives an element at the index 0 that doesn't exist.

You have it in the exception: IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 (you're trying to get the element at 0 (the first), but the size is 0. So the index you're asking for, is out of the bounds of the list)

Comment: To better understand how it works, you can replace the content of the method by 

    `public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
       return "index "+ rowIndex +", col "+ columnIndex;
    }
    `
this way you will see the position of each element in your table